# Usando tr("...") en Qt

Tags: qt

Cuál es la diferencia al crear un objeto `QString` del framework **Qt** 5 al usar `tr("...")` o no, por ejemplo:

```
QString("texto");
QString(tr("texto"));
```

¿Para qué me sirve el `tr()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tr()` es una función de **Qt** que te facilita el soporte multilenguaje de tu aplicación. Todo el texto que vaya a ser visible para el usuario, debería mostrarse como `QString(tr("texto"));`. De este modo, con la ayuda de la librería **QtLinguist**, es muy sencillo crear aplicaciones multilenguajes creando los ficheros de traducción. [Aquí](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtlinguist-hellotr-example.html) te dejo un enlace a un tutorial/ejemplo de lo que te estoy contando.

Espero que te sirva. Saludos